# how can i get my orthographic camera view 's height and width in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I have a orthographic camera that is set to my box2d world, and I need to get the camera's view width and height, how can I do that?

Comment: Just declare variables WIDTH and HEIGHT in world units, and pass those variables to the OrthographicCamera constructor. Depending on your project size and structure, you might want to store these as static variables in a `Constants` class, or store them as instance variables in your main project class.

Comment: I too advice you to set your camera like @DJMethaneMan said. Otherwise your camera might be 1280x720 which translates to 1280mx720m which is, depending on your game, most probably not wanted. The short answer would be `camera.viewportHeight` and `camera.viewportWidth` will get you the dimensions of the viewport used by your camera.

Comment: Reading the documentation of the class would have been way faster than coming on here and typing out a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Camera's viewportWidth and viewportHeight properties[1](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#viewportWidth). I.e.:

```
float width = camera.viewportWidth;
float height = camera.viewportHeight;
```